# Can second harmonic generation be stronger than fundamental frequency interaction in metals/dielectric nanoparticles?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, nanoscience

Quick question regarding non-linear optics:

A nanoparticle, either dielectric or metallic present second harmonic generation. The dielectric, following the simplest modelization as:

$$E(2\omega)\propto P^{(2)}(2\omega)=\chi^{(2)}E(\omega)E(\omega).$$

A metal nanoparticle, following the hydrodynamic approximation, see Ref. 1, equation (4) for the second order polarizations.

Due to the quadratic dependence on the fields, upon increasing the delivered power, the second harmonic scattering and absorption (in metals) can surpass that of the fundamental frequency (that grows linearly). That is, the second order scattering cross sections can be higher than the fundamental ones.

Is that physically reasonable? Or there is some saturation of the effect? Or a breakdown of the models?

I find it puzzling that the SHG process can be stronger than the fundamental one.

References:

1. A. Capretti, C. Forestiere, L. Dal Negro, G. Miano, "Full-wave analytical solution of second-harmonic generation in metal nanospheres", [arXiv:1301.1628](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1628).